# this field is required in angular form submission

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to do post request but unable to a sit is showing **400 bad request** and the response is **this field is required**. The request payload is showing empty object.

> **service.ts**

```
sendRole(data){
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
}).set('Authorization', 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('usertoken'));
var options =  {
  headers: headers
};
return this.httpClient.post('api/auth/role/', data, this.options)
.map((res:Response)=> res.json())
.catch(this.handleErrorObservable); 
}

private handleErrorObservable (error: Response | any) {
console.error(error.message || error);
return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
}
```

> **component.ts**

```
addRole(){
  this.Authentication.sendRole(this.role)
  .subscribe(role=> this.roles =role)
}
```

> **component.html**

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Role:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" name="role" #role>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addRole(role.value)">Submit</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

**network tab**
[image: network tab]

**request payload**
[image: request payload]>

**network response**
[image: network response]>

Comment: while calling `addRole()` in component you are passing some data but in function you are not recieving it. so make it `addRole(data:any)`

Comment: there is no data sent from your end.

Comment: `this.role` should be object like `{name: this.role}`, I think you `data` contains only `this.role`. check `console.log(data)` in the service and before calling the service

Comment: Its still showing the same error. Also if i console data, it is showing undefined.

Comment: From where you are getting `this.role`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting `role` in `addRole()` function on `onclick`. Change your component code to like below

In the **template** you are passing `role`

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addRole(role.value)">Submit</button>
```

In the **ts** file change code like below

```
addRole(role){ // here pass role
  this.Authentication.sendRole({ 'name': role }) // not this.role only role and send it as object
  .subscribe(role=> this.roles =role)
}
```

Working example is here in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arrpqd)

Comment: Ok, now im getting the body but now its showing another error called "Unsupported media type "text/plain" in request."

Comment: @JijoRobin then set `Accept` header to `application/json`

Comment: @JijoRobin And one more thing, how you are getting payload now, can you post the image of that?

Comment: the payload is showing the data I'm entering in text box.

Comment: I'm trying to append like this   headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');  but its showing  Property 'append' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: @JijoRobin I mean like an object or plain text

Comment: as plain text :(

Comment: @JijoRobin I've updated my code add role function in component, check once

Comment: @JijoRobin If you find the answer helpful, please make it as accepted one and upvote also ;-)

Comment: hey buddy, i need your help again. You must be thinking what now? But you were  really patient with me. I'm a beginner so I would really appreciate your help. Here's the link.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702664/edit-and-delete-operation-in-angular

Comment: @JijoRobin ;-) checking